# Applying a custom Function to a Pandas Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame (condensed here) called master_df

| Ticker | Date | Total_Invested | Total_Divested | Period | Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 23-10-2020 | 200 | 210 | 1 | 1 |
| BCK | 23-10-2020 | 200 | 220 | 1 | 1 |
| DUD | 22-10-2020 | 200 | 190 | 1 | 2 |
| SOL | 22-10-2020 | 200 | 205 | 1 | 2 |

I created a function to return the % return for a given day:

```
def day_return(df, date):
    day_df = df[df['Date'] == date]  
    return day_df['Total Divested'].sum()/day_df['Total Invested'].sum()-1
```

I'd like to use Groupby and the function together to get the return for each day.  My thought was do the following but I keep getting stuck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
master_df.groupby('Date').apply(day_return, date=master_df['Date'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the *date* argument from the function *day_return* and just group by *Date*, in a group all values will correspond to same value:

```
def day_return(df):
    return df['Total_Divested'].sum() / df['Total_Invested'].sum() - 1

res = master_df.groupby('Date').apply(day_return).reset_index(name='Total')
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
         Date   Total
0  22-10-2020 -0.0125
1  23-10-2020  0.0750
```

If you want to add a new column to the original df (*master_df*), use [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
g = master_df.groupby('Date')
master_df['Total'] = g['Total_Divested'].transform('sum') / g['Total_Invested'].transform('sum') - 1
print(master_df)
```

**Output**

```
  Ticker        Date  Total_Invested  Total_Divested  Period  Day   Total
0    ABC  23-10-2020             200             210       1    1  0.0750
1    BCK  23-10-2020             200             220       1    1  0.0750
2    DUD  22-10-2020             200             190       1    2 -0.0125
3    SOL  22-10-2020             200             205       1    2 -0.0125
```

Comment: Thanks, when I run that, I get the below error.  I think I'm getting stumped by calling a DF column in the function                                                                                                
          TypeError: day_return() missing 1 required positional argument: 'date'

Comment: @redgabe You need to modify the function. remove the date argument as in my code

Comment: thanks, modified.  How do I keep some other non-numberic columns from the Dataframe (that are not listed above)?

Comment: @redgabe Please add the expected output, from what you say it seems that you are looking for something more than an apply.

Comment: @mesejo410 I added the two other columns above.  Thanks

Comment: Yes but what is the output for those, an apply operation will change the shape of the output ie does not have the same number of rows as the original dataframe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226516/discussion-between-dani-mesejo-and-redgabe).